# About a word "pitiful"

Tags: word-meaning

> **Death had been more pitiful to them than longer life would have been.**
>   It had taken the one in the loyalty of love, and the other in the
>   innocence of faith, from a world which for love has no recompense and
>   for faith no fulfilment.

This is from a novel "A Dog of Flanders". I read the translation of this sentence "Death had been more pitiful to them than longer life would have been." and it says it means "The death was better for them than longer life would have been.". But when I looked a word "pitiful" up in dictionaries, it means "sad, pity", so does it mean "The death was worse for them than longer life would have been.", doesn't it? When I read following sentences, I think it can be interpreted either. Could you teach me?

Comment: In older English it could mean "full of pity"; compare "merciful". The psychology of why a word can switch from describing the person feeling to the thing they're feeling about is probably fascinating. In any case, "Death would have been kinder to them than longer life."

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Does a word "pity" mean  "merciful" now?

Comment: @Yuuchi Tam: The word **pity** means **compassion, mercy** not "merciful", which is an adjective that applies to someone who feels pity.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Thank you for your comment. Luke Sawczak said it could mean "full of pity" In older English, so I wondered if "pitiful" means "merciful" and "pity" means "mercy" now.

Comment: Luke said the adjective **pitiful** could mean "full of pity". In your comment, you ask about the noun **pity** (not the adjective "pitiful").

Comment: Then,  can "pitiful" mean "full of pity" now?

Comment: **Pitiful** is not used to mean "pitying, full of pity" in standard contemporary English, where it means "to be pitied, wretched".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blatantly stealing Luke Sawczak's and Tᴚoɯɐuo's comments to answer the question:

"Pitiful" has changed somewhat in meaning from when the novel was first written.  At that time it meant something closer to "merciful" or "compassionate".

See Definition 3 [here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pitiful), marked "archaic".  So in this case the writer is saying that death is better for the subject than a long life would be.